# How to get a DataGridView column's index in a MouseUp event, not in a MouseDown event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, onmouseup

I have a WinForm with `DataGridView`, my goal is to drag one column and drop it on other column index. I know column reordering is possible by using `AllowUserToOrderColumns = true`. But I have to perform other operations on DGV. That's why I need the target column index at a mouse-up event. To do that, I use `HitTestInfo`:

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid.HitTestInfo myHitTest;
myHitTest = dataGrid1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
int p = myHitTest.ColumnIndex;
```

When I click on the first DGV column, this code runs and gives me the column's index (`p`). The problem is when I drop it on the other column of DGV, I'd like to know the target column's index, with the same code `p = -1`, I think because the `HitTestInfo` member returns a value on a `MouseDown` and **not** on a `MouseUp`. If anyone can tell me how to do it, it would be very great.

Comment: You can add a MouseUp event by going to the designer view > select yout dgv > go to events> and double click MouseUp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two HitTestInfo objects, one in the `MouseDown` and one in the `MouseUp`.

IMO, you also should use the `DataGridView.HitTestInfo` class, not `DataGrid.HitTestInfo` and try to not call or name `DataGridViews` `DataGrids`, which is a similar but different Control from `WPF`!

```
DataGridView.HitTestInfo myHitTestDown, myHitTestUp;
int visibleColumnDown, visibleColumnUp;

private void dataGrid1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myHitTestUp = dataGrid1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    visibleColumnUp = getVisibleColumn(dataGrid1, e.X);
}

private void dataGrid1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    myHitTestDown = dataGrid1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    visibleColumnDown = getVisibleColumn(dataGrid1, e.X);
}
```

**Update:** To find the visible index of a column after the columns have been reordered simply use:

```
dataGrid1.Columns[myHitTestUp.ColumnIndex].DisplayIndex;
```

Before I found that, I wrote this little helper function, which does the same:

```
int getVisibleColumn(DataGridView dgv, int x)
{
    int cx = dgv.RowHeadersWidth;
    int c = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
    {
        cx += col.Width; if ( cx >= x) return c; c++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

To find out which Column was shuffled seems to be a bit harder. There is an event, which gets called for **each** column that was **affected** and it always gets called first for the one that was dragged along. Here is one way to do it:

Create to variables at class level:

```
List<DataGridViewColumn> shuffled = new List<DataGridViewColumn>();
DataGridViewColumn shuffledColumn = null;
```

Remember the first column:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(
             object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (shuffledColumn == null) shuffledColumn = e.Column;
}
```

Forget what happend before:

```
private void dgvLoadTable_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{  
    shuffledColumn = null;
}
```

Now you can use it. Selecting Columns is, however, not going well with shuffling them! If you do

```
 shuffledColumn.Selected = true;
```

it will only be selected if the `SelectionMode` is either `FullColumnSelect`or `ColumnHeaderSelect`- In either mode the shuffling will not work, I'm afraid..

Comment: it works for drag n drop but when I do reshuffle same column continuously then ColumnIndex at mouseup gives wrong index where i am dropping.

Comment: Ah, that's right. Didn't notice the shuffling, sorry. I have added a helper function to my answer.

Comment: It's is very very useful for me. could you suggest a code that while reshuffle the column, shuffled column should be selected at mouse up event .

Comment: Actually it may be of interest but I found a much simpler way to find out the displayIndex of a column. See me edit. As for selecting a column, this is not as simple as it seems, because of the contradictions between `SelectionMode` and the reordering of the Columns.

Comment: I have made a sample here [Download sample project from here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3CZaLjGYNiJamFPZXZQQ2g3RFU&usp=sharing). When I reshuffle same column then reshuffled columns are not getting selected correctly. Here columns are getting selected randomly. please correct this code.

Comment: int getVisibleColumn(DataGridView dgv, int x)
{
    int cx = dgv.RowHeadersWidth;
    int c = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
    {
        cx += col.Width; if ( cx >= x) return c; c++;
    }
    return -1;
} it doesn't work when any column width is larger and any column which is smaller width drop at larger column then it gives wrong index plss correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use drag'n'drop for that.
Assume you have a `Form` with a `DataGridView` named `dataGridView1`.

Initially don't forget to allow drag'n'drop for `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView1.AllowDrop = true;
```

The event handler which replaces the desired functionality of `MouseUp` would be the `dataGridView1_DragDrop`, and the target column's index is `colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop`:

```
private Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;
private int colIndexFromMouseDown;

private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
        if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty &&
            !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
        {
            // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                    
            dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(colIndexFromMouseDown, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the index of the item the mouse is below.
    colIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;

    if (colIndexFromMouseDown != -1)
    {
        // Remember the point where the mouse down occurred. 
        // The DragSize indicates the size that the mouse can move 
        // before a drag event should be started.                
        Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;

        // Create a rectangle using the DragSize, with the mouse position being
        // at the center of the rectangle.
        dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(
            new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2), e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)),
            dragSize);
    }
    else
        // Reset the rectangle if the mouse is not over an item in the ListBox.
        dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // If the drag operation was a move then remove and insert the column.
    if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
    {
        // The mouse locations are relative to the screen, so they must be 
        // converted to client coordinates.
        Point clientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Get the column index of the item the mouse is below. 
        int colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex;
        if (colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop == -1)
            return;
        colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.Columns[colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop].DisplayIndex;
        // Now we have the column's display index.

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(int)))
        {
            int colToMove = (int)e.Data.GetData(typeof(int));
            dataGridView1.Columns[colToMove].DisplayIndex = colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop;
            // Select the column:
            dataGridView1.Columns[colToMove].Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
New approach:

```
private DataGridViewColumn columnToMove;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[]
        {
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "AAA", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable },
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "BBB", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable },
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "CCC", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable }
        });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.MouseDown += dataGridView1_MouseDown;
    dataGridView1.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += dataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged;
}

private void dataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column == columnToMove)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
        e.Column.Selected = true;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
    {
        columnToMove = dataGridView1.Columns[hti.ColumnIndex];
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...it works for drag n drop but when I do reshuffle continuously then int colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex gives wrong index where i am dropping.

Comment: Look at the next 3 lines. The `colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop` is being corrected there: `colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dataGridView1.Columns[colIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop].DisplayIndex;`

Comment: @AnkitSingh was it clear enough? If so, was the answer helpful?

Comment: It's is very useful for me. could you suggest a code that while reshuffle the column, shuffled column should be selected at mouse up event .

Comment: @AnkitSingh You could set the `Selected = true` for the desired column. I've updated my answer. Please revise.  If I answered your initial question, you should mark it as accepted: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you have another question, please ask it separately.

Comment: Please check it doesn't work when we do same column reshuffle . it do selected any column randomly.

Comment: @AnkitSingh I cannot understand what exactly you are talking about. Please download the [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2SR1OxxycOISjB1RnFic2EzVlk/view?usp=sharing) to make sure everything works as expected

Comment: Could you plss help me out with this sample [Sample project](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3CZaLjGYNiJamFPZXZQQ2g3RFU&usp=sharing). please correct this . It doesn't work while reshuffling same column, reshuffled column not get selected properly .it get selected randomly . plss plss

Comment: @AnkitSingh I've added a new approach. Please revise.

Comment: Dmitry I need one help plss?