# Reshuffled DatagridView columns are not getting selected properly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have made a sample here [Download sample project from here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3CZaLjGYNiJamFPZXZQQ2g3RFU&usp=sharing). When I reshuffle same column then reshuffled columns are not getting selected correctly. Here columns are getting selected randomly. please correct this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the column on which the `MouseDown` is raised and then select it in the `MouseUp` event:

```
private DataGridViewColumn columnToMove;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[]
        {
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "AAA", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable },
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "BBB", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable },
            new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "CCC", SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable }
        });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.MouseDown += dataGridView1_MouseDown;
    dataGridView1.MouseUp += dataGridView1_MouseUp;
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)
    {
        columnToMove = dataGridView1.Columns[hti.ColumnIndex];
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (columnToMove != null)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
        columnToMove.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Sample project: [download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2SR1OxxycOIMFNZNElvbVBabE0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @AnkitSingh Yes, and there is no problem, because it will be set in the `MouseDown` event handler. Does this code work as you expected?

Comment: absolutely its working for me only one thing is remaining that when select a column without reshuffling it doesn't select the column. while reshuffle it is working. please suggest that one also.

Comment: @AnkitSingh I've updated the answer. Download link was also updated. If my answer was helpful, you should mark it as accepted. And do the same for my previous answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26449464/2878550).